# Apresentação de dados na view com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou tentando apresentar os dados vindos do meu banco de dados na View. Segui os diversos tutoriais que encontrei na internet porém nenhum deles conseguiu me atender :/.

**Model**

```
public function get_titles() {
    $title = $this->db->get('TB_TITLES');
    return $title->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function titulosCadastrados($page = 'titulosCadastrados') {
    if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/titulos/'.$page.'.php')) {
        show_404();
    }
    $data['titles'] = $this->title_model->get_titles();
    $this->load->view('templates/system-header');
    $this->load->view('pages/titulos/titulosCadastrados', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/system-footer');
}
```

**View**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>  
        <?php foreach ($titles as $title) { ?>
            <tr><?php echo $title->name ?></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Tabela no banco de dados**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_titles(
ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),
VALUE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
PAID_OUT_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
REGISTERED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

O erro apresentado é:

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: titulos/titulosCadastrados.php
>
> Line Number: 39
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> C:\CibraProgramas\Xampp\htdocs\financas\application\views\pages\titulos\titulosCadastrados.php
> Line: 39
> Function: _error_handler

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está em `get_titles()` você pede que seja retornado um array contendo outros arrays e não um array de objetos. A forma de acessar um array é diferente de acessar um objeto por isso o erro na view.

Mude:

```
public function get_titles() {
    $title = $this->db->get('TB_TITLES');
    return $title->result_array(); //retorna um array de arrays
}
```

Para:

```
public function get_titles() {
    $title = $this->db->get('TB_TITLES');
    return $title->result();
}
```

**Documentação:**

[results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays)

Comment: Obrigado @rray, funcionou. Só uma observação, tive que alterar o valor que eu queria acessar (No meu caso, nome) da mesma forma que está no banco (Tudo em uppercase): $title->NAME

Comment: @Csorgo no caso de objetos o nome propriedade deve ser escrita da mesma forma que foi escrita no banco de dados. Se for utilizar arrays no lugar de objetos, pode converter as chaves com [array_change_key_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php)